# Java Socket: Check if Client socket is disconnected

Tags: java, serversocket

I have a thread that waits for a client to send a request. This thread is a while loop, and once it receives an ObjectDataStream from the client, it sends an OutputDataStream to the client. This is all good and works perfectly.

I have another thread that deals with checking if client sockets are disconnected. The way I'm doing this is by:

- placing all connected clients into a data structure
- looping over each socket in this data structure
- sending a DataOutputStream to this socket
- check if DataOutputStream works. If it does => client is still connected. If it doesn't work, client disconnected => remove client from data structure and start looping again

Now the main problem I'm facing is that the thread that is dealing with disconnected sockets is interrupting the DataStreams between the server and client.

Client code: It sends a Request object and waits for a boolean response from the server.

```
outToServer.writeObject(request);
boolean loggedIn = inFromServer.readBoolean();
return loggedIn;
```

Server Code: Checks if username and password are valid and returns a boolean based on it. Then it sends this boolean to the client.

```
boolean loggedIn = Server.loginUser(username, password, clientSocket);
outToClient.writeBoolean(loggedIn);
```

Thread which deals with disconnected clients:

onlineClients: 
`public static Map<Socket, User> onlineClients`

```
while (true) {
    for (Iterator<Socket> iter = onlineClients.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        Socket client = iter.next();
        try {
            DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            outToClient.writeUTF("Client you there?");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Removing client: " + client.getPort());
            iter.remove();
            System.out.println("There are : " + onlineClients.size() + " online clients");
        }
    }
}
```

When the above threads runs, it interrupts the `boolean loggedIn = inFromServer.readBoolean();` part of code where `loggedIn` should be true but it becomes false. I know this because if I comment out the thread, `loggedIn` become `true`. So I thought maybe `outToClient.writeUTF("Client you there?");` is interrupting it.

My code is too long so I tried my best to summarise as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should never write to a stream from two threads without proper synchronization!

On way is to wrap all your sections that write data to the stream into synchronized blocks:

```
synchronized(client) {
    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
    outToClient.writeUTF("Client you there?");
}


synchronized(clientSocket) {
    boolean loggedIn = Server.loginUser(username, password, clientSocket);
    outToClient.writeBoolean(loggedIn);
}
```

If both sections synchronize on the same object you are safe because only one thread can execute inside a synchronized block.

Comment: Yes but that won't stop `outToClient.writeUTF("Client you there?");` from being sent and affecting `boolean loggedIn = inFromServer.readBoolean();`

Comment: I found a small but maybe ineffective solution which is to use `Thread.sleep(2000)` before `outToClient.writeUTF("Client you there?");`